# Django 2.2 Задать в админке динамичные полья для регистрации пользователей разных классов(модератор, редактор, пользователь)

Tags: django, django-admin, django-filter

Я пытаюсь создать дополнительные поля для каждого класса пользователя, но пока не разобрался как использовать динамические поля которые отличаются зависимости класса пользователя например:

1. Модератор
   при регистрации будет только использовать базовые поля без дополнений,
2. Редактор
   при регистрации надо будет указать личные данные и соответственно нужны
   дополнительные поля
3. Пользователь
   тоже будет указывать личные данные с предпочтениями и историей просмотров
   статей

Я использую этот код для привязки UserProfile для добавления кастомного поля для регистрации пользователя:

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birthdate = models.DateField()
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags, verbose_name='Теги статей')
//.....


class RadactorProfile(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_title = models.ManyToManyField(Posts, verbose_name='Post title')
    total_posts = models.IntegerField(null=True)

//.....
```

admin.py

```
class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'UserProfile'
    fk_name = 'user'

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (ProfileInline, )

    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return list()
        return super(CustomUserAdmin, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj)
```

как мне реализовать выборку в admin где будет появятся нужные поля для нужных классов пользователей?

Comment: хм. при нажатии на кнопку добавить можно перенаправить на промежуточную view, на который выбираем кого добавлять. В зависимости от выбора перенаправляем на того или иного типа юзера. сойдет?

Comment: все это делается через админку и надо туда добавил поля

Comment: Оооо, так вы можете попробовать в записимости от типа, через JS скрывать ненужные инлайн блоки

Comment: попробую сделать так поставлю проверку на системе